# Facebook share button not showing the thumbnail image?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm confused. I have the `og` tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.chineselearnonline.com/wp-content/themes/clo/assets/img/images/clo-fb-white.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="Chinese Learn Online | Progressive Mandarin Course">
<meta property="og:description" content="See why thousands of students just like you are raving about the unique, progressive immersion method to learn Mandarin Chinese.">
```

It shows fine on the Facebook debugger:

[image]

But I don't see thumbnail preview:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Facebook button code:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=128928147210470&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/level-test/" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

Live site:

http://www.chineselearnonline.com/level-test/

Image:

[image]

Comment: Shows up when i paste the [link into facebook post](http://i.imgur.com/caFvg2F.jpg), maybe facebook's service that fetches the page could not get the image at that particular moment

Comment: @Patrick Evans Weird, then why doesn't show with the Facebook Share button?

Comment: Your button has  `data-href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/level-test/"` that url gives me a 404, should it be `www.`? If I change it to www it shows up in the sharer correctly. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/t6F3Ba0.jpg), [Direct sharer link](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chineselearnonline.com%2Flevel-test%2F).  Like I said maybe when you tested it at that point in time facebook's server couldn't get the image, but now can. Have you tried doing a forced refresh and trying to do a share (maybe your browser is caching the share fetch)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hey, you're right. It's fixed. Could you post this as a answer so I can select it?